# Asp.Net 2.0 and Asp.Net 3.5 code compilation models – are there any differences?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I've just started to learn about Asp.Net 3.5 compilation model, but most articles mostly talk about Asp.Net 2.0 compilation model and how it differs from previous versions of ASP.NET compilation model. So I wasn't able to find any article explaining if there are any differences between ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5 compilation models. Thus:

A) do CodeBehind,Src, CodeFile and Inherits attributes act  exactly the same in both ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5?

B) where do Asp.Net 2.0 and Asp.Net 3.5 compilation models differ?

Comment: Is there such a thing as ASP.NET 3.5?

Comment: There certainly is for my Project and Account Manages - thank you very much MS. The amount of confusion this has caused: "But you said you'd used 3.5, and it's running on 2.0...". Grrr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Yes.

B) The 3.5 compiler has some additional cleverness built in to handle things like Extension Methods, but there's no real difference between the process of compiling a 2.0 Web Application and a 3.5 Web Application, nor is there any difference with running a 2.0 web site project on a 3.5 server - if you take a look in IIS, the version of ASP.NET it thinks it's running on is 2.0.

Comment: To add to your statement, it's completely a new C# compiler used, nothing is changed in the ASP.NET itself.

Answer (score 3):

The compilation system is not redesigned in ASP.NET 3.5. It's the same system as of 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

As Mehrdad said, it's the same in ASP.NET 2.0 and 3.5.

But there are differences between the two web project types: **Web Site Project** and **Web Application Project**. You can find more details on [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5) to decide which one is better suited for you.